# Fixer api reporting - cannot load no 'access-control-allow-origin'

Tags: angularjs, api, cors

I am using fixer.io api for currency conversion api in my angularjs website. It was working good in the past. But in the recent times it started to produce the below error.

> xmlhttprequest cannot load no 'access-control-allow-origin'

So on research I found out the this is something to do with CORS. And few of them suggest using http.jsonp instead of http.get. But fixer.io doesn't support http.jsonp format.

Few also suggest to use the below headers in the config.js which did not help.

```
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With']
```

Many say that this is a server side thing and adding a header will not help. Is there a way to fix this problem from my side? Or if I switch to a different provider who support http.jsonp format, do you think it will solve this issue?

**EDIT**

[API URL](http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD)

Comment: can you provide me api url if possible?

Comment: @PareshGami Please look at the edit....

Comment: I think this api need authentication

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">

    {{records[0]}}
    <div ng-repeat="rate in rates">
        {{rate.currency}}--{{rate.rate}}<br>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope,$http) 
{
    var url = 'http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

    $http.jsonp(url)
    .success(function(data)
    {
        $scope.rates=[];

        for(var key in data.rates) 
        {
            var obj = {
                        "currency":'',
                        "rate":''
                    };

            var value = data.rates[key];

            obj.currency=key;
            obj.rate=value;

            $scope.rates.push(obj);
        }
    });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```